# Pandas get most frequent values used together in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains only two columns `user_id` and `channel`. Channel column can assume values from a pre-defined list `[a,b,c,d]`. There are multiple rows with the same `user_id`. Each row can contain any of the above channels.

If I consider the unique channels that each user visited, what set occurs most frequently?

Example dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'b'], [1,'b'], [2,'c'], [2,'a'], [2,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'a'], [3,'b']], columns=['user_id', 'Channel'])
>>> df
   user_id Channel
0        1       a
1        1       b
2        1       b
3        1       b
4        2       c
5        2       a
6        2       a
7        2       b
8        3       a
9        3       b
```

Expected solution:

for the above example would be something like:

- For `user_id == 1` the set of unique Channels is `{a, b}` and that counts once for that combination.
- For `user_id == 2` the set of unique Channels is `{a, b, c}` and that counts once for that combination.  Note that this does not count for **any** subsets of these unique Channels.
- For `user_id == 3` the set of unique Channels is `{a, b}` and that counts once for that combination.

If we count the **one** combination of unique Channels for each `user_id` we should get

```
>>> df_result = pd.DataFrame([['a,b', 2], ['a,b,c', 1]], columns=['Channels_together', 'n'])
>>> df_result
  Channels_together  n
0               a,b  2
1             a,b,c  1
```

I have come up with a solution which is to pivot the table so that I get `user_id`, and columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` then assign an integer to each Channel column if not NA, then sum across columns and convert back the results to each combination.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I can't seem to find out how.

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: `df.groupby('channel').count()`?

Comment: no I need observations that are frequently together, not just most frequent in a group.

Comment: Create a small test dataset and show your expected results from this small test dataset.

Comment: Based on your example dataset, what is the expected output?

Comment: For my specific use I think Erfan's answer is correct.

Comment: please help me re formulate the question title to clarify if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby.apply(set)` and then count the values with `.value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('user_id')['Channel'].apply(set).value_counts()\
  .reset_index(name='n')\
  .rename(columns={'index':'Channels_together'})
```

**Output**

```
  Channels_together  n
0            {a, b}  2
1         {a, c, b}  1
```

---

If you want your values in `str` format we can write a `lambda` function to sort our set and convert it to string:

```
df.groupby('user_id')['Channel'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(set(x)))).value_counts()\
  .reset_index(name='n')\
  .rename(columns={'index':'Channels_together'})
```

**Output**

```
  Channels_together  n
0              a, b  2
1           a, b, c  1
```

Comment: Thanks Erfan! Your first solution gave me the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` but the second one works perfectly!!

Comment: Depend on how you look at it. The result makes sense to me if you just get unique values per group. @piRSquared , but I understand your approach as well, but it's different than OP expects.

Comment: OP clarified in their comments.  I agree.

Answer (score 2):

#### `frozenset`

Is hashable and can be counted

```
df.groupby('user_id').Channel.apply(frozenset).value_counts()

(a, b)       2
(a, b, c)    1
Name: Channel, dtype: int64
```

And we can tailor this to precisely what OP has with

```
c = df.groupby('user_id').Channel.apply(frozenset).value_counts()
pd.DataFrame({'Channels_together': c.index.str.join(', '), 'n': c.values})

  Channels_together  n
0              a, b  2
1           a, b, c  1
```

Alternatively

```
df.groupby('user_id').Channel.apply(frozenset).str.join(', ') \
  .value_counts().rename_axis('Channels_together').reset_index(name='n')

  Channels_together  n
0              a, b  2
1           a, b, c  1
```